# Python, attain a certain text from html

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to attain a certain text that is written in korean. Is there a more efficient way of doing this, rather than converting it to a string and parsing it from there?

CODE:

```
#input:     url
#output:    name
def urlSC(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    name = soup.find('span', id = 'lblKName')
```

OUTPUT:

```
<span id="lblKName">구세군앵커리지한인교회<br>The Salvation Army Anch. Korean Corps.</br></span>
```

Want:
구세군앵커리지한인교회

url: http://www.koreanchurchyp.com/ViewDetail.aspx?OrgID=4102

Comment: you don't need 'span' either `id= 'lblKName'` will do the same job.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: and I didn't see that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the korean part of the text is always at the first part  before a br tag, you can use :

```
name = soup.find(id = 'lblKName').contents[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

1. BeautifulSoup can take a **file handle**, vs the HTML string. This is slightly simpler, and might be faster if your text is nearer the beginning of the page.

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
   ```
2. Another option is a **regular expression**. They're quite fast, but also a challenge to build correctly, and will break if the page format changes. Stick with BeautifulSoup unless you get stuck.
3. BeautifulSoup can use several different parser libraries, with different space/time/reliability tradeoffs.  See: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Good advice, but this doesn't answer the original question that was asked, though.